# How to use mobile layouts in PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, mobile, view, pyrocms

I'm trying to use mobile layouts so that `PyroCMS` will choose the correct layout automatically if the user is visiting with a mobile device.

I have my `MyTheme/views/web and MyTheme/views/mobile`.
The web views get loaded as they should, the mobile views however do not.   When I use an `android` or `iphone` simulator I don't get the mobile-views, I just get the web-views.

why? is there something I have to enable, or is there somewhere I can go to perhaps get an error message and see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mobile safari` was not added to mobile user agents, that was why it wasn't registered